# Multiple dex files define Ljavax/annotation/Generated;

Tags: android, gradle

I've faced a strange trouble when running tests.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':data:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Ljavax/annotation/Generated;
```

But my application is build and run quite ok. Any ideas?